# Auto-Clicker Code Not Working (First Project)

Tags: python, multithreading, time, listener, pynput

I'm trying to use pynput to make an autoclicker as my first project, but I'm having a tough time understanding why my code won't work. The code is meant to start/stop clicking when I hit *"ctrl + alt + i"* and click once every 1 second. Here is my current code. I can't really understand why it doesn't work, but what I have made work so far is that *"click_thread.running"* is changing from true to false, python listens to my keyboard, and the clicking works **ONLY WHEN** I set the *"self.running"* in the *"ClickMouse"* class to true. The output I get from printing *"click_thread.running"* seems to change from true to false, but if that's happening then why doesn't the clicking start? I would imagine it has something to do with how it's a subclass of *"threading.Thread"*? Or maybe I made the class wrong? Either way I've been working on it for a few days now and I feel like I have hit a wall trying to figure it out alone. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import keyboard

delay = 1
button = Button.left

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super().__init__() 
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button                
        self.running = False             

    def run(self):
        while self.running == True:
            mouse.click(self.button)
            time.sleep(self.delay)

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()

def on_activate_i():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+i pressed')
    if click_thread.running == False:   
        click_thread.start_clicking()
    else:
        click_thread.stop_clicking()
    print(click_thread.running)

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<ctrl>+<alt>+i': on_activate_i,}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `click_thread.start()`, the `start` handler is going to call your `run` function in the new thread.  At that point, `self.running` is `False`.  Thus, your while loop will immediately exit, and the thread will end.

So, set `running=True` as the default, and don't create the thread until `on_activate_i`.

Where are you clicking?  At random?

Comment: I was hoping to make the clicking turn on and off again when I trigger on_activate_i, starting with off. Since you can't start a thread more than once, in there a way to keep the while loop and the thread going?